# Connecting to another PC in LAN via sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

So I'm trying to connect to another PC via TCP protocol using sockets, 192.168.1.72 is another PC's address, however, I'm not relly sure im going the right road. I have server also oon different computer, and theese two programs seem to work well on same computer, when in line with `_clientSocket.Connect();`, i use `IPAdress.Loopback` instead o `host`. Am I doint the right aproach, or should i look elsewhere, and if i am, how can i make this function work, because now it simply crashes and indicates there is something wrong with `host` declaration

```
    private static void LoopConnect()
    {
        IPAddress host = new IPAddress(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("192.168.1.72"));


        int attempts = 0;

        while(!_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                _clientSocket.Connect(host, 100);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());

            }
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");


    }
```

Comment: can you add information about what "something is wrong with host declaration" means? do you have an exception with stacktrace?

what type of app are you developing? console? wpf? xamarin?

Comment: As you mention you have indications something is wrong with your host declaration - you should post any such error messages/indications so people here can see it too - it will greatly improve your chance of getting help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply the IP adddress as a string, you need to use the static [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
IPAddress host = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.72");
```

Comment: Holy crap that actually worked, I've been dealing with this for 8 hours, thanks so much